# ¿Como no mostrar los nodos deshabilitados?

Tags: php

```
<xen:title>{xen:phrase create_thread}</xen:title>
<form action="{xen:link 'brqct-create-thread/create-thread'}" method="post"     class="xenForm formOverlay">
<dl class="ctrlUnit">
    <dt><label for="ctrl_node_id">{xen:phrase forum}:</label></dt>
    <dd>
        <select name="node_id" class="textCtrl selectForum" id="ctrl_node_id" autofocus="true" >
            <option value="" ></option>
            <xen:foreach loop="$options" key="$ai" value="$node">
                <option value="{$node.value}" {xen:if '{$node.disabled}','disabled="disabled"'}>{xen:string repeat, '&nbsp; ', $node.depth}{$node.label}</option>
            </xen:foreach>
        </select>
    </dd>
</dl>
<dl class="ctrlUnit submitUnit">
    <dt></dt>
    <dd>
        <input type="submit" value="{xen:phrase create_thread}" accesskey="s" class="button primary" />
    </dd>
</dl>
<input type="hidden" name="_xfToken" value="{$visitor.csrf_token_page}" />
```

la clave esta aca

```
<xen:foreach loop="$options" key="$ai" value="$node">
  <option value="{$node.value}" {xen:if '{$node.disabled}','disabled="disabled"'}>{xen:string repeat, '&nbsp; ', $node.depth}{$node.label}</option>
</xen:foreach>
```

como le hago para que se salte los disabled?

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/470100779353505802/470101221663965185/unknown.png?width=501&height=342

Quiero que los disabled, en lugar de esten gris, no aparezcan.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba poniendo un if para evitar los disabled

```
<select name="node_id" class="textCtrl selectForum" id="ctrl_node_id" autofocus="true" >
  <option value="" ></option>
     <xen:foreach loop="$options" key="$ai" value="$node">
        <xen:if is="!{$node.disabled}">
          <option value="{$node.value}">{xen:string repeat, '&nbsp; ', $node.depth}{$node.label}</option>
        </xen:if>
     </xen:foreach>
</select>
```